# Which are good ASIHTTPRequest alternatives?

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am currently developing an application , that will be published on appstore. I only need for my application to be able to send a json file to a server. I am currently using asihttprequest for this ONLY post method , but this class is not longer developed by the developer. What i want to ask is , if the latest version of asihttprequest is reliable for an application or if i should use an alternative? If yes , please provide me an alternative.

Comment: Did you try google or search here before posting?

Comment: Yes i did.. what i need is a developers opinion.. Actually many.. I think this is the best place to ask..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go either for [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit) or [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But is there a reason that i shouldnt "trust" asihttprequest for this particular single action?

Comment: The author stopped working on it... You should always try to use 3rd party libraries that are updated regularly..

Answer (score 0):

FTR, as per [this blog post](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2012/07/19/say-hello-to-fsnetworking-a-small-networking-library-for-ios-and-mac/), Foursquare released an [FSNetworking](https://github.com/foursquare/FSNetworking) library, which might be a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

HI i prefer using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) as for the reason of not trusting ASIHTTprequest is

- not being maintained
- It gave problem on iPod1+ iOS6 combination  [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641997/asiformdatarequestclass-not-working-for-ios6)