# ASIFormDataRequestclass not working for iOS6

Tags: ios

im my app i am using ASIFormDataRequest class but it seems they are not working for devices upgraded to iOS6.

I am always getting **null response**

Any suggestions? or is there a new version online?

I previously thought its ASIHTTPRequest but error seems to be in ASIFormDataRequest...

Thanks

**Issue Update**

ASIFormDataRequest web services is not working on  iPod1+iOS 6 in my apps but is working fine on iPad and iPhone...

Comment: didn't have any problems with my old apps.

Comment: Mine not working will give details soon

Comment: Moved on to afnetworking was a challenge but turned out to be good

Comment: unfortunately AFNetworking hasn't a plug&play cache system

Comment: which one is best and what you think abut other people taking over ASIHTTPRequest? @meccan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASIHTTPRequest is no longer being maintained. The developer stopped working on the project, so an update for iOS 6 may never come (I haven't tested it with iOS 6 myself, so I don't know if the problem is surely due to iOS 6).

You may slowly want to move on to other libraries. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is an example.